# Android aar in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, native, aar

i'm developing a plugin for unity. my question is how to build an aar library from dependency defined in gradel file. or any other alternative way to integrate the android library in unity3D.

Comment: I am getting the sense there are two questions here. How to build an aar file is one and integrating into unity is another. What have you tried? What does your Gradle file look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Found out a solution,
built an android project and picked library from local file system and imported it as module , after that once again compiled the project and found .aar file into **module_name**/build/output/aar/**module_name.aar**